# How to import icons in Gatsby.js using the sprite SVG icon file method?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Does any one know how to import individual icons using the SVG sprite method (As seen here: https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/ in Gatsby.js?